# how to make a div inside a td cell overlap the next td

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to be able to position the div (element E) inside the TD cell (element C) without the other TD cell (element D) getting pushed to the right.

Note: **I can't edit anything on that page except for element E.**

Comment: have you tried the `float: left;` style?

Comment: Do you have the ability to wrap `E` in a container `div`?

Comment: @Jeremy: I have tried it, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Negative right margin ought to do the trick: `margin-right: -50px;`.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/peteorpeter/dvr9Z/

Absolute position *could* work, but adds other complications.  Tables + absolute position can be painful, especially with fluid content.

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work in IE7. (The orange box is completely inside the first cell.)

Comment: @ThatMatthew Not terribly surprising. I suppose since it looks like this is a (partially) table-based layout, he might need to support IE < 8... is that stereotyping? Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to - that the left `td` content doesn't get pushed down by the `div`?  If so, you just need to give the `div` some [content](http://jsfiddle.net/5dyWP/1/).  (I'm not sure what behavior you are looking for on the right?)

Comment: Looking back at your OP makes me think you are probably also thinking about `element G`.  That does make this a hairier problem...

Comment: Wow. This is a weird scenario.  Can you change CSS on any of the other elements? Does E have a fixed height?

Comment: weird & frustrating indeed, can't edit any CSS other than element E's. It will display a banner 728x90 so I don't think it needs a fixed height.

Comment: Can you call your own javascript?  It's not ideal, but you could do some manual layout tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot edit any other element except for element E itself:

Move element `E` to a container:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   <div id="element-E" style="position:absolute;"> ... </div>
</div>
```

I've added `style` attributes to the elements, because you alleged to not be able to modify other elements (such as `<style>`).

`position:relative` is required to correctly absolutely position a child element.

`position:absolute;` "tears" the element from its parent, and places it back again, relative to the upper-left corner of the parent (by default, when the position hasn't changed using `top` for example).

Comment: You'll need to set an absolute height on the containing element for this to work; otherwise the `<td>` won't expand in height to match the element inside

Comment: True. He also has to change the `width` and`height` CSS property of `element-E` if he wants to. Since he didn't specify anything about size, I excluded these at my answer though.

Comment: @Rob W: I added width and height to element-E, but it didn't work, the TD cell (element D) still gets pushed to the right

   `<div style="position: relative;">
<div id="element-E" style="position: absolute;width: 750px;height: 100px;"> ... </div></div>`

Comment: Your code has to look like this: `<tr><td><div style="position:relative;heght:1.2em;"><div id="element-E" style="position:absolute;">..</div></div></td><td><!--Element-D--></td></tr>`. (Change `1.2em` to the actual height of your table-cell. If you're able to edit the table style, use `vertical-align:top` instead (either at the row or cell).

Comment: Great input! now element D doesn't gets pushed to the right anymore, BUT unfortunately I can't get the content inside the element D cell to move down [check out this code](http://jsfiddle.net/bogdanch/nGsHJ/1/).

Comment: Some methods to move the element: 1) `<td id="element-D" style="padding-top:50px;" ...` 2) `<td id="element-D"><div style="height:50px;"></div>...` 3) Same as 2, instead of `height`, use *margin:25px*, *margin-top:50px*, *margin-bottom:50px* 4) `<td id="element-D"><br /><br />...` (last resort).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the height of the `<div>` is 100px and the combined width of the two `<td>` cells is 500px try:

```
td.element-e-container { 
  position:relative; 
  height:100px; 
}
#element-e{
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Then give the td containing element e a class of `element-e-container` and the element itself an ID of `element-e`

Comment: Assuming you can add another DOM element, this works nicely.  Using absolute position allows you to simply set a fixed width on `e`.  OTOH, if @Bogdan has to use the markup at hand (or wants to minimize HTML tags) negative right margin would work.